# Web deployment projects for Visual Studio 2005 - can't find plugin on MSDN?

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project

The Visual Studio 2005 web deployment project plugin used to be here:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/Aa336619.aspx

This just goes to the ASP.NET home page now, and I've had no luck Googling (or ... Binging?) for it. Does anyone know if this is still available for download anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Wayback Machine at the internet archive

https://web.archive.org/web/20060212040155/http://msdn.microsoft.com/asp.net/reference/infrastructure/wdp/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This article still has an active link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx

Direct Link: [WebDeploymentSetup.msi](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/c/b/ccb4877f-55f7-4478-8f16-e41886607a0e/WebDeploymentSetup.msi)

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried this, but it's a pre-release version and my existing projects aren't happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a the service pack "SP1" for Visual Studio 2005 which has the web deployment project included in it.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88fx1xy0%28VS.80%29.aspx#sp1webappproj)

Also, do note that this SP1 installation REALLY takes lot of time to complete.

Comment: The Web Application Project is included indeed, but I haven't found the Web _Deployment_ Project (.wdproj)...